# How to Select an dropdown element with Span tag in Selenium

Tags: html, selenium

I'm trying to select an option from Dropdown with Span tag in Selenium. Below is my Selenium code

```
new Select (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.select2-selection.select2-selection--single"))).selectByVisibleText("Prison");
```

Getting error `'org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "span"'`

HTML Code for the dropdown is as below;

[image: HTML code]

Kind request for any help.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your code. Insert it in a codeblock.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use  in select class. Try 
`Select sel = new Select(driver.findelement(By.id('P37_ACCOMMODATION_STATUS')));
sel.SelectByVisibleText('Prision');`